# How to get specific columns in EF Core 7 with ANNOTATIONS

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-core, data-annotations

I am trying to learn how to use EF Core.
I am using VB, with EF Core 7, MySQL DB and I am trying to do a localized App where the columns of a table are localized.
I scaffolded the DB and I have these entities:

```
Partial Public Class Board
    <Key>
    <Column("BoardID")>
    Public Property BoardId As Integer

    <StringLength(100)>
    <CustomDisplayName("BoardName")>
    Public Property BoardName As String

    <Column(TypeName:="text")>
    Public Property Description As String

End Class

Partial Public Class Item
        <Key>
        <Column("ItemID")>
        Public Property ItemId As Integer

        <Column("BoardID")>
        Public Property BoardId As Integer?

        Public Property CreationDate As DateOnly?

        Public Property LastModifiedDate As DateOnly?

        <StringLength(100)>
        Public Property Title As String
End Class

Partial Public Class Subitem
    <Key>
    <Column("SubitemID")>
    Public Property SubitemId As Integer

    <Column("ItemID")>
    Public Property ItemId As Integer?

    <Column("CreatorUserID")>
    Public Property CreatorUserId As Integer?

    Public Property CreationDate As DateOnly?

    Public Property LastModifiedDate As DateOnly?

    <Column(TypeName:="text")>
    Public Property Description As String
```

If I do this:

```
Using Context As New Context
 Dim result = Context.Boards.ToList
GridControl1.datasource = result
End Using
```

The Localization caption is working, but is showing me all the columns from all the 3 tables like inner join them and I want only from the boards table.

If I do this:

```
Using Context As New Context
 Dim result = Context.Boards.[Select](Function(Boards) New With {Boards.BoardName, Boards.Description}).ToList
GridControl1.datasource = result
End Using
```

Shows exactly what columns I want, but the annotation will not work because of the anonymous type.

I also tried:

```
Using Context As New Context

    Dim data = Context.Boards.AsQueryable()
    data = From recordset In Context.Boards Select New Board With {
    .BoardName = recordset.BoardName,
    .Description = recordset.Description
}

    Dim Result As List(Of Board) = data.ToList()
    GridControl1.DataSource = Result
End Using
```

But is not showing only 2 columns, is showing all the columns from the inner join. Localized caption is working.

Any suggestion:

1. How to show the two columns with custom data annotation working?
2. How to show only boards table not a inner join of the 3 tables ?